# Open new browser windows in background using CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

How can I open a new browser in the background?

I trying to use *window.open*, but the new windows always open with focus.

I tried to do:

```
popup = window.open(@pop_url, '', 'width=,height=,resizable=YES')
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to remove the focus from the new window using `blur()` and set the new focus to your parent window using `focus()`:

```
popup = window.open(@pop_url, '', 'width=,height=,resizable=YES');
popup.blur();
window.focus();
```

But be aware since this method has been used in the past mainly for user unfriendly behavior or content this will be blocked my most popup blockers - even though this method is actually called popunder.

Comment: As mentioned this method will most likely no longer work, since browsers adopted to that behavior.